# MIPS "Invalid language element:" on symbol names like 1try_msg

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mips64

```
    .data
    Initial_msg: .asciiz "\nLet's play a guessing game. \nFind out the number between 1 and 10 that I generated. \nEnter 0 to give up\n\n"
    Bigger_msg: .asciiz "\nMy number is bigger than that one...\n"
    Smaller_msg: .asciiz "\nMy number is smaller than that one...\n"
    Right_Answer_msg: .asciiz "\nYou've got it!"
    Game_Over_msg: .asciiz "\nNo more tries, I've won!\n"
    2tries_msg: .asciiz "You got two more tries.\n\n"
    1try_msg: .asciiz "You got one more try.\n\n"
    Number_msg: .asciiz "The number I chose was: "

    # $s0 -> Random number generated by the computer
    # $s1 -> Number chosen by the player
    # $s2 -> Number of tries

.text
main:
    li $v0, 42 # syscall code to generate a random number
    li $a1, 10 # sets the upper bound to 10
    syscall
    
    move $t0, $a0 # moves the genrated number to register $t0
    add $s0, $t0, 1 # add 1 to the number generated between 0-9
    add $s2, $zero, 3 # sets $s2 to the number of tries

    li $v0, 4 # syscall code to print a string
    la $a0, Initial_msg 
    syscall

    action:
        li $v0, 5 # syscall code to read an integer
        syscall
        move $s1, $v0 # saves in $s1

        beq $s1, $zero, end # verifies if the player has given up
        beq $s0, $s1, got_it # checks if the player has gotten right the number

        sub $s2, $s2, 1 # decreases the number of tries remaining
        beq $s2, $zero game_over # the number of tries have reached zero

        slt $t0, $s1, $s0
        beq $t0, 1, its_bigger

    its_smaller:
        li $v0, 4 # syscall code to print a string
        la $a0, Smaller_msg 
        syscall
        j more_actions

    its_bigger:
        li $v0, 4 # syscall code to print a string
        la $a0, Bigger_msg
        syscall

    more_actions:
        beq $s2, 2, 2_tries # restam 2 tentativas
        beq $s2, 1, 1_try # resta 1 tentativa

        j action

    2_tries:
        li $v0, 4 # syscall code to print a string
        la $a0, 2tries_msg 
        syscall
        j action

    1_try:
        li $v0, 4 # syscall code to print a string
        la $a0, 1try_msg 
        syscall
        j action

    got_it:
        li $v0, 4 # syscall code to print a string
        la $a0, Right_Answer_msg 
        syscall
        j end

    game_over:
        li $v0, 4 # syscall code to print a string
        la $a0, Game_Over_msg 
        syscall

        li $v0, 4 # syscall code to print a string
        la $a0, Number_msg 
        syscall

        li $v0, 1 # syscall code to print a integer
        la $a0, ($s0) # prints the number chosen by the computer

end:
    li $v0, 10 # Ends the game
    syscall
```

MIPS assembly language program, I need your help in MIPS assembly's program. Compiling with some errors,

2tries_msg: .asciiz "You got two more tries.\n\n"
Invalid language element: 2tries_msg

Error in line 8 column 2:   1try_msg: .asciiz "You got one more try.\n\n"
Invalid language element: 1try_msg

Error in line 55 column 15:         beq $s2, 2, 2_tries # restam 2 tentativas
Invalid language element: 2_tries

Error in line 56 column 15:         beq $s2, 1, 1_try # resta 1 tentativa
Invalid language element: 1_try

Error in line 60 column 2:  2_tries:
Invalid language element: 2_tries

Error in line 62 column 11:         la $a0, 2tries_msg
Invalid language element: 2tries_msg

Error in line 66 column 2:  1_try:
Invalid language element: 1_try

Error in line 68 column 11:         la $a0, 1try_msg
Invalid language element: 1try_msg

Assemble: operation completed with errors.

Please help me to resolve the errors.

Comment: Don't use digits as the first character of a label name.

Comment: The first hit in my google search for `site:stackoverflow.com mips assembly "Invalid language element"` was the linked duplicate which explains the problem.